# Error opening network folder

Tags: active-directory, file-server

I have a file server with SMB2 protocol that authenticates users through AD.

I am mapping the drive by network IP. However, at some point, I can not open the drive, gives mapping error not found. This happens with some IPS only. When I replace the IP, it works again. It also works again when I restart the server. AD and FileServer are the same server.

Has anyone had this problem. Below log from Microsoft Network Monitor. There are no error events in the event viewer.

> SMB2  SMB2:R  - NT Status: System - Error, Code = (22) STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED  SESSION SETUP (0x1), SessionFlags=0x0 
>   SMB2    SMB2:R  - NT Status: System - Error, Code = (52) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND  CREATE (0x5) , File=desktop.ini@#372 
>   SMB2    SMB2:R  - NT Status: System - Error, Code = (22) STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED  SESSION SETUP (0x1), SessionFlags=0x0 
>   SMB2    SMB2:R  - NT Status: System - Error, Code = (22) STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED  SESSION SETUP (0x1), SessionFlags=0x0 
>   SMB2    SMB2:R  - NT Status: System - Error, Code = (52) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND  CREATE (0x5) , File=desktop.ini@#4330 
>   SMB2    SMB2:R  - NT Status: System - Error, Code = (22) STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED  SESSION SETUP (0x1), SessionFlags=0x0 
>   SMB2    SMB2:R  - NT Status: System - Error, Code = (22) STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED  SESSION SETUP (0x1), SessionFlags=0x0 
>   SMB2    SMB2:R  - NT Status: System - Error, Code = (22) STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED  SESSION SETUP (0x1), SessionFlags=0x0 
>   SMB2    SMB2:R  - NT Status: System - Error, Code = (22) STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED  SESSION SETUP (0x1), SessionFlags=0x0 
>   SMB2    SMB2:R  - NT Status: System - Error, Code = (22) STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED  SESSION SETUP (0x1), SessionFlags=0x0 
>   SMB2    SMB2:R  - NT Status: System - Error, Code = (186) STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY  CREATE (0x5) , File=Arquivos\Financeiro@#9394 
>   SMB2    SMB2:R  - NT Status: System - Error, Code = (186) STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY  CREATE (0x5) , File=Arquivos\Financeiro@#9401 
>   SMB2    SMB2:R  - NT Status: System - Error, Code = (22) STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED  SESSION SETUP (0x1), SessionFlags=0x0 
>   SMB2    SMB2:R  - NT Status: System - Error, Code = (186) STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY  CREATE (0x5) , File=Arquivos\Financeiro@#9936 
>   SMB2    SMB2:R  - NT Status: System - Error, Code = (22) STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED  SESSION SETUP (0x1), SessionFlags=0x0 
>   SMB2    SMB2:R  - NT Status: System - Error, Code = (22) STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED  SESSION SETUP (0x1), SessionFlags=0x0 
>   SMB2    SMB2:R  - NT Status: System - Error, Code = (22) STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED  SESSION SETUP (0x1), SessionFlags=0x0 
>   SMB2    SMB2:R  - NT Status: System - Error, Code = (22) STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED  SESSION SETUP (0x1), SessionFlags=0x0 
>   SMB2    SMB2:R  - NT Status: System - Error, Code = (186) STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY  CREATE (0x5) , File=Arquivos@#12450 
>   SMB2    SMB2:R  - NT Status: System - Error, Code = (186) STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY  CREATE (0x5) , File=Arquivos@#12452

Comment: Map the folder with NET USE T: \\server\folder.  For server use the Name or IP Address exactly as you used here. What numerical error do you get?

Comment: System Error 67 Appears

Comment: Error 67 is a configuration error between workstation and server.  Google for Windows Server Error 67.  See if this thread helps you:  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/9c429bef-edf0-4bad-83a3-644e6ba28ea8/net-use-system-error-67?forum=winservergen

Comment: What is your OS? I assume Linux here given that you mention SMB?

Comment: Windows Server 2012